# iOS app cpu usage decreases when press UIButton

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I am creating a game for iOS. The game is written as a C++ library so that it can be ported to another platform. I am also using Swift and Objective C to call the game update, draw functions and process user input etc. in the view controller.

I am having and issue where the game begins to stutter when I press a UIButton to perform some action in the game. I have noticed even when the UIButton callback function is empty, the game still stutters.

The game idles at ~30% CPU usage. When I press the button, the cpu usage drops to ~15% for a few seconds, then gradually makes its way back up 30%. It's during this time that the game stutters.

It seems to me that when the button is pressed, the operating system is allocating fewer resources to the app, causing it to slow down.

To try and resolve this problem, I have put the game update function on a new thread to take some weight off the main thread. This did not work.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: It's hard to say without understanding *what* is happening when the button is pressed. (I'd ask for code but unless it's Swift you may need to remove that tag.) Many variables come to mind. How are you working UI - main thread or background? What other things are happening when a button is pressed? What is being done in C++? Is this SpriteKit? SceneKit? How are you calling the C++ code? The bottom line is that **many** things may be happening, and using *pure* Swift should never mean "stuttering". It's up to *you* to give more details for us to be of help.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail. I did not give many details about the C++ library because the app stutters even when I remove the code that calls the C++ func in the UIButton func (Swift). To  answer your questions. 1) UI is worked on the main thread. 2) Nothing happens when the button is pressed, it is an empty function. 3) I am using C++ to simulate the game, which involves drawing to screen using OpenGL, animating 3D models, AI etc. All of this runs fine, until a button is pressed that does nothing.

Comment: Wow. Never heard of anything like that. So if you basically removed everything but Swift code, maybe you have a MVCE? Code that we can reproduce this?

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll try to make one now.

Comment: I have just found that the reason for the app stuttering is because the button press somehow affects the current time in milliseconds, which is done using time.h in C++. Using delta time provided by GLKit fixes the stuttering problem. I am not sure why this would be affected. I calculate the current time in milliseconds in c++ using  (double)(clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC. I'll adjust my question.

Comment: I'm not a C++ programmer, so this is just a guess. GLKit uses the GPU, and it's possible that other pieces (you mentioned draw functions) may also. Maybe things are bridging from the CPU to the GPU... and using C++, back?

Comment: I use the GPU in C++ by drawing to screen with OpenGL ES. I do not communicate from the GPU to the CPU (Not that I'm aware).